# Django REST api and django_filter problem

Tags: django, rest, filter, django-rest-framework

I have problem with `rest_framework.viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet`.

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    meat_type = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='slug__iexact')
    category = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='slug__iexact')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'price': ['gte', 'lte'],
        }
        ordering_fields = ['price', ]


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def get_products(self, request):
        products = self.get_queryset().order_by('-created')
        serializer = self.get_serializer_class()(products, many=True)
        print('SHOW IT')
        if len(products) == 0:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My problem is that `print` in `get_products` not work, but code give good result with filters objects. My urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('', views.ProductViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/', include(router.urls))

]
```

Tests:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.url = "/api/shop/"
        self.search_url = "/api/shop/?price__lte={}&price__gte={}&meat_type={}&category={}"

        self.category1 = Category.objects.create(name='cattest1',
                                                 slug='cattest1')
        self.category2 = Category.objects.create(name='cattest2',
                                                 slug='cattest2')
        self.meat_type1 = MeatType.objects.create(name='meattest1',
                                                  slug='meattest1')
        self.meat_type2 = MeatType.objects.create(name='meattest2',
                                                  slug='meattest2')
        self.product1 = Product.objects.create(category=self.category1,
                                               meat_type=self.meat_type2,
                                               name='prodtest1',
                                               slug='prodtest1',
                                               price=50)
        self.product2 = Product.objects.create(category=self.category1,
                                               meat_type=self.meat_type1,
                                               name='prodtest2',
                                               slug='prodtest2',
                                               price=75)
        self.product3 = Product.objects.create(category=self.category2,
                                               meat_type=self.meat_type2,
                                               name='prodtest3',
                                               slug='prodtest3',
                                               price=20)
        self.product4 = Product.objects.create(category=self.category2,
                                               meat_type=self.meat_type1,
                                               name='prodtest4',
                                               slug='prodtest4',
                                               price=150)

    def test_get_products_all(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(4, len(response.data))

    def test_get_products_no_content(self):
        Product.objects.all().delete()
        response = self.client.get(self.url)
        self.assertEqual(204, response.status_code)

    def test_product_greater_than(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.search_url.format(
            "", "55", "", ""
        ))
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(2, len(response.data))
```

Test `test_get_products_no_content` fail with error:
**assertionError: 204 != 200**.
Somebody have any idea?
Thanks for any answer
Magnus

EDIT
Created this function, is pass good data to filter.
**DICT {'price__lte': '50', 'price__gte': '100', 'meat_type': 'wieprzowina'}**
But I have problem when I put it as filter argument. Got error:
**invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'wieprzowina'**. It try to change string to number, but I dont know why.

```
    def get_queryset(self):

        filter_params = self.request.query_params
        filter_params_dict = {k: str(v) for (k, v) in filter_params.dict().items()
                              if v is not None and str(v) != ""}
        print('DICT', filter_params_dict)
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(**filter_params_dict)
        return queryset
```

EDIT 2:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meat_type = models.ForeignKey(MeatType,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,
                            db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150,
                            db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              default='no-image.png')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('price',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:detail',
                       args=[self.category.slug, self.id, self.slug])
```

Comment: Which `TestCase` you're using? from django? That might be because previous test already remove all Products so that `test_product_greater_than` can't find any products and then return 204 code instead of 200

Comment: `from django.test import TestCase`, but this is not problem.

Comment: I though that your filter works fine but after you update the question I think you should check your filterset instead of create a new function. You can print the sql queries so that we might now which cause the issue and that would be great if you can include your model into the question. Now I think the problem is your filter doesn't return any data, this issue has nothing to do with `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect url ,you should use this url for your custom action:

**/api/shop/get_products/**

The url you are using i.e **/api/shop/** will call the default list action of the viewset not your custom action and thats why you are getting 200 status code always

You can read more about viewset here:
[ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

Comment: Okay, now is call `get_products` function, but it doesnt filter data. How can I fix it? I try to override `get_queryset`. I can get filter parameters by `self.request.query_params` this is Query dict, how can I pass it to Product.objects.filter?

Comment: I try do this like here: [https://coderwall.com/p/gtwm1q/pass-a-querydict-to-a-django-queryset], but got error: **ValueError at /api/shop/get_products/**.

Comment: Updated my post, could you look on it?

Comment: What is the data type of your meat_type field?Is it char or int?

Comment: I put my Product model in post.

Comment: meat_type field is a foreign key(i.e  MeatType Model's primary key), so it is of integer data type and you are filtering meat_type against a string.Thats why you are getting that ValueError. Change your meat_type filter to an integer value.

Comment: But Im want filter by slug no by id, In early method it works by default. Now after all changes with urls etc. it doesnt work.

Comment: You can use this to filter by slug: DICT {'price__lte': '50', 'price__gte': '100', 'meat_type__slug': 'wieprzowina'}